# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. ERROR

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

We have some third party code that is causing some misery at the moment due to throwing the above error: it is slightly odd because it is an intermittent error. Here is the method that is causing the issue:

```
    Private Shared Sub IntLocateDictionaries(ByVal haystack As ExpDictionary, 
        ByVal needlearray() As Object, _
        ByVal resultarray() As Object, ByVal removemarks As Boolean)

        Dim i As Integer
        Dim item As Object

        For i = 0 To UBound(needlearray)
            If haystack.Exists(needlearray(i)) Then
                resultarray(i)(CStr(resultarray(i).Count + 1)) = haystack
                If removemarks Then
                    ExpandIT.FileLogger.LogError("*********** REMOVING From HAYSTACK - COULD CAUSE EXCEPTION! ***************")
                    haystack.Remove(needlearray(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next

        ' Scan for sub dictionaries
        For Each item In haystack.Values
            If TypeName(item) = "ExpDictionary" Then 
                IntLocateDictionaries(item, needlearray, resultarray, removemarks)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

...and this is the calling line:

```
        currencyproducts = New ExpDictionary
        priceproducts = New ExpDictionary
        IntLocateDictionaries(info, New Object() {"_cc", "_csp"}, New Object() {currencyproducts, priceproducts}, False)
```

I understand that this error is usually caused by trying to modify a collection whilst enumerating around it, hence why I've added logging on the only line that looks like might alter the collection...

Since adding the logging we have still experienced the issue but NO LOGGING appears: this isn't surprising since if you look at the parameters on the calling line (the only place this Sub is called from) - removemarks is passed as False - this will be passed all the way down through the recursive calls and so that line which calls .Remove never gets executed....the fact we don't see logging proves this....

Can anyone see anything else that might cause this issue!!!

Thanks all

Richard

Answer (score 1):

It is  a recursive method. It seems this line is causing the error

`If removemarks Then haystack.Remove(needlearray(i))`

Here the `needlearray(i)` might be modified by the inner recursive method which will cause the outer recursive method to throw this error

Comment: Yes....I thought that line looked like the culprit but if you look at the calling code, the parameter [removemarks] is passed in as False. This, surely, means that line of code should never execute!?

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating the `haystack.Values` collection and then recursively calling back in which may call this line:

`If removemarks Then haystack.Remove(needlearray(i))`

Now reading the code, it should work because your iterator is on `haystack.Values`, not `haystack`.  But I have no idea what the `Remove` method does, perhaps it touches `.Values`?

You have two ways to address this:

- Use a for loop and count backwards through the list, and remove by index.
- Gather a list of things to remove and do them at the end when the iterator has finished.

I'm fairly certain LINQ comes with a Remove function that takes a lambda.

Comment: Yes....I thought that line looked like the culprit but if you look at the calling code, the parameter [removemarks] is passed in as False. This, surely, means that line of code should never execute!?

Comment: If it's false it will be false for the entire duration and shouldn't cause the exception.  But I'm fairly confident that the only line visible in this code that would cause this error is the `.Remove` call.

Comment: I totally agree - but I have done a search on the entire web app for IntLocateDictionaries and it is only called in the one place I specified above - and that passes False for [removemarks]...hence, why I'm totally baffled!

Comment: Unless it's called via Reflection.  I can't help any more than I have.